# Javascript classList add hidden not working

Tags: javascript, html

Below is a snippet of code that gets some elements via the DOM. I just attach a simple onclick which is supposed to add the "hidden" property to the classList of each retrieved element.

HTML:

```
<body>
        <h1 id="view-one-header">Exploring View 1</h1>
        <img id ="dragonite" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/8/8b/149Dragonite.png" alt="Dragonite">
        <button id="toggle-view-two-btn">Toggle View 2</button>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = pageLoad;

function pageLoad() {
    let viewOneHeader = document.getElementById("view-one-header");
    let dragoniteImg = document.getElementById("dragonite");
    let toggleViewTwoBtn = document.getElementById("toggle-view-two-btn");
    toggleViewTwoBtn.onclick = changeToViewTwo;

    function changeToViewTwo() {
        viewOneHeader.classList.add("hidden");
        dragoniteImg.classList.add("hidden");
   }
```

I am trying to debug this script because when the button is clicked, the corresponding views do not disappear. It has been awhile and I am unable to figure out the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your code is working as is. The "hidden" class gets added to the elements with the id's specified. You must need to update the css to make the "hidden" class, actually hide.

Comment: You must show the related HTML and CSS for us to be able to help. If, for example, `let toggleViewTwoBtn = document.getElementById("toggle-view-two-btn");` is being executed prior to that element being read into the DOM, then `toggleViewTwoBtn` will be `null` when you attempt to assign the `.onclick`.

Comment: @colecmc There is no possible way for you to know if the code is working as is and that there is just a CSS issue. We don't have enough information.

Comment: Yes, I can know @ScottMarcus because I ran the code provided without changing it at all. I added the HTMLElements with the id's and the classes were added. Did you do that?

Comment: Did you add the elements before or after the script? How do you know that the OP placed the script in the same location as you did? My point is that there are more reasons why the code doesn't work than just CSS so you can't be sure of the problem at this point. And, if you can't be sure of the problem, you can't say what the solution must be.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the problem as I understand it right now, is because of missing CSS. If the OP has a different problem, than feel free to clarify by editing the post.

Comment: @colecmc How did you come to the conclusion it's missing CSS? The OP didn't show any HTML so couldn't you also come to the conclusion that the problem is that there is no HTML? What if there is HTML and CSS, but no element with an `id` of: `toggle-view-two-btn`? As I say, there are many possibilities for failure right now. It's premature to claim that you know what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have added some css for the class "hidden". When you click on the element with the id "toggle-view-two-btn" the classes are added.

```js
let viewOneHeader = document.getElementById("view-one-header");
let dragoniteImg = document.getElementById("dragonite");
let toggleViewTwoBtn = document.getElementById("toggle-view-two-btn");
toggleViewTwoBtn.onclick = changeToViewTwo;

function changeToViewTwo() {
    viewOneHeader.classList.add("hidden");
    dragoniteImg.classList.add("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="view-one-header">view-one-header</div>
<div id="dragonite">dragonite</div>
<div id="toggle-view-two-btn">toggle-view-two-btn</div>
```

Comment: Again, this doesn't answer the question. It just shows working code. We don't know enough about the OPs situation to be able to provide an answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, if you read the question asked, you'll notice a keyword "disappear". What does that reference?

Comment: *"when the button is clicked, the corresponding views do not disappear"* This could be because the DOM element references for updating the `classList` are not valid, it could be because the event handler is not set up correctly and it could be because there is a CSS problem. You were correct in your answer, after all, but that doesn't negate that it was a guess and just as easily could have been wrong.